Kafka Producer Key Shows Incorrect Value After Sending Message
I am working on a Spring Boot application where I am using Kafka to send messages to a topic. I am setting a specific key for each message, but after successfully sending the message, when I check the topic, the key is showing as a random number instead of the key I set.
I have set below code in my app,
application.properties
spring.kafka.producer.key-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.IntegerSerializer
spring.kafka.producer.value-serializer=org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer

.
I am using avro schema to send values, everything working fine, data is sending to kafka also.
Can anyone tell me what may be the issue,
Thanks in advance.


Please share your producer code and what you are seeing when you consume. Refer [mre] 2) If you are using avro schema, then you need to use AvroSerializer, not int or string serializer


Yes i set the avroserilizer for value.but still issue.

ProducerRecord<String, MyClass> producerRecord =new ProducerRecord<>(topicName,key, wrapper.getData())
sendToKafka (wrapper.getData(), producerRecord);

Please [edit] your question to include code. Your properties are using integers for keys and strings for values. This does not match the code you've provided. Instead, you need ProducerRecord<Integer, String>, or correct the properties... So, maybe it's "random" since you're not using the correct serialization formats

done but still same issue
